# OAuth 2.0 strategies for Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm building a Chrome extension that adds features to Gmail.

To accomplish this, I need oauth 2.0 access to the Google Contacts and Gmail APIs.

Originally I was using a technique/library outlined here: [OAuth 2.0 in Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth)

That was working fine with the Contacts API, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with the very new Gmail API. It seems to send the oauth request as uri parameters, each parameter prefaced with 'oauth'. It also appears to be around 4 years old, last updated about two years by looking at the HEAD.

I then moved on the chrome.identity API, using the chrome.identity.getAuthToken() flow for google accounts. This worked awesome... for the chrome account that's linked to the currently logged in Gmail account. If a user logs into a different gmail account that doesn't match the address of the currently logged in chrome account, all my REST interactions go kaput. Which they should.

So I've moved on to using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() method, which seems to be the updated version of the first method / library I had tried. The problem here is that an access token seems to be limited to just an hour before requiring a re auth? (Meaning pop up UI, etc) Not ideal for an app used over the course of a workday.

Has anyone here managed to gain long term access tied to more than one email address for an extension?

At this point it seems my best option is just making sure I have helpful UI modals to either

A. make sure the user is logged into chrome under the same address they are logged into gmail under

or

B. Have helpful UI convincing users that reauthorizing every hour is necessary for security. (not terrible, still annoying).

Thanks in advance for any insight!